# Identify Duplicates and Compare Value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search for duplicates within a contiguous range, and, if a duplicate is found, to compare the value in a separate range (analogous rows) and pick the lesser one to delete.

It's easy enough to tell it to compare duplicates and clear x-many rows for so many columns.

```
Dim LR as long
Dim LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Activesheet.Range("$A$1:" & "G" & LR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlGuess
```

But one would need to use a range like Z:Z and compare the found duplicate (in A & B) against the original and see if, for example Z3's cell contents (4) are greater than Z200's cell contents (6), and delete row 3.

The idea is to go from this:

[image: Starting Info]

To This:

[image: Ending Info]

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed it, in a dirty way.

I created a hidden column with =Counta(E:Z) (or what have you)
So I then got it to sort by First, the Case Number, then by the hidden column (descending). That way, when I used the remove duplicates script, he with the least data was mowed down.

It worked for me.

```
 Dim LR As Long
 LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("D2:E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:E" & LR)
 Range("A2:Z" & LR).Select
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("B2:B" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("D2:D" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:AG" & LR)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:AG" & LR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2),    Header:=xlGuess
```